# Rust macro extremely slow (increase expenentially) and with high disk usage

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I have a crate that generate code with macros using `quote` and `proc_macro2::TokenStream`.
When the size of the generated code increase a little, the compilation time explodes exponentially, and the disk usage of my SSD stays at 100% for a few minutes.

What advice should I follow to keep the compilation time reasonable?

For example, when the code generates one "element", it takes 15 seconds, but for 5 elements, it takes 15 MINUTES, 60 times more.

During most of the 15 minutes, it only uses the CPU (a lot). But at the end, for a few minutes, the disk usage is 100%.

What could explain the unreasonable disk usage by rustc when the code produce by the macro grows?

It is reproducible on two different computers, one with Windows 11, the other Ubuntu 22. Both with an SSD, and largely enough ram (so it can't be a swap problem).

I've set-up two branches to reproduce: `macro1` and `macro2` in https://github.com/tdelmas/floats

The diff between the two: https://github.com/tdelmas/floats/compare/macro1...macro2

/!\ **DO NOT open the branch `macro2` on vscode**, between the background build that takes 15 minutes (with 100% disk usage on the end) and rust-analyzer, it will be hard to work.

To reproduce:

(all those steps were done on a terminal, with vscode - and rust-analyzer - closed)

**The slow macro is only called in the code that generate test**, so we can pre-build the app (and the dependencies) with `cargo build` first and then build the app with tests (that needs that macro to be built) with `cargo test --no-run` (anyway the tests are fast, less than a second)

```bash
# initialisation
git checkout https://github.com/tdelmas/floats
cd floats
```

Then we can prepare the build for `macro1` with:

```bash
git switch macro1
# to remove any previous build
cargo clean
# dowload and build deps, the build without the impacted feature
cargo build
# build with the problematic macro
cargo test --no-run
```

That last command took 14 seconds on my Windows and 15 on my other computer with Linux (Ubuntu).
(slow, but reasonable)

To compare with the other branch `macro2`:

```bash
git switch macro2
# to remove any previous build
cargo clean
# dowload and build deps, the build without the impacted feature
cargo build
# build with the problematic macro
cargo test --no-run
```

And that last command, that build with the macro that is problematic, with took 15 **MINUTES** on my Windows and 8 minutes on my Linux.

The code between the two branches should not change in complexity, only in size. If we assume that most of the time is spent in the code where the diff is, then the build should take at most 5 times more, not 60.

Or did I make a catastrophic mistake in my code?

I use in this version:

```rust
output.extend(quote! {
  #add
  #sub
  #mul
  #div
  #rem
});
```

Where `#add`, `#sub`, ... are generated before with (simplifying): `let add = quote! { ... }`,
but the previous version had one call to `output.extend` per var, and was as slow (I changed it to limit the number of call to `output.extend`, but that had apparently no impact.).

I can probably avoid the problem by generating less code with macros and adding methods on my objects to run more code at runtime is I don't understand why the build time explode, but I would really prefer not to and understand what's happening here.

More context:

The problematic macro is called here: https://github.com/tdelmas/floats/blob/macro1/typed_floats/src/lib.rs#L106

The call to `#add` and 4 others is in a double loop (of 12 elements each, from `get_specifications`).
They all generate a similar code by calling `test_op_self_rhs` (which calls `test_op_checks`). None of those function contains any loop. They just concatenate `quotes!`.

- First loop: https://github.com/tdelmas/floats/blob/macro1/typed_floats_macros/src/lib.rs#L309
- Second loop: https://github.com/tdelmas/floats/blob/macro1/typed_floats_macros/src/lib.rs#L343

These two loops generate all combinations of `NonNaN`,`NonNaNFinite`, `NonZeroNonNaN`, `NonZeroNonNaNFinite`, `Positive`,`PositiveFinite`, `StrictlyPositive`, `StrictlyPositiveFinite`, `Negative`,`NegativeFinite`, `StrictlyNegative`, `StrictlyNegativeFinite` to generate the tests that:

- verify that the output types of the operations (like `+`) is not too strict
- verify that the output type is as strict as possible

The functions `XXX_result` like `add_result` take two times as parameters, and the list of all types, and determine the resulting type if we add two number of those types. (if the result of that function is `None` it means that it may be `NaN` thus none of those types fit and `f64` must be the return type for that operation)

(Cf https://crates.io/crates/typed_floats)

Crosspost: https://users.rust-lang.org/t/rust-macro-extremely-slow-and-with-high-disk-usage/96281

Comment: did you confuse SO with githib issue tracker ?

Comment: You claim "large enough RAM" but did you actually verify that the compiler isn't using all of it?

Comment: @Stargateur no, I didn't. No need to be this rude. I'm the author of that (typed_floats) crate, I'm trying to improve it, and I have a performance problem when writing rust macros, and I'm asking guidance for that. 
Is that performance problem a bug? If not, what should I do to improve the code and avoid that performance problem. If it's a bug, how can I get around it and check if it is a known or if I should report it.

Comment: @Thomas Yes I did chech: during the build, around 8gb of ram was used, of the 16 and 32 my computer have, so more than half was free.

Comment: Is the extra running time caused by the macro itself, or by compiling the generated code? Did you try to inspect the _output_ of the macro? Maybe it's doing something you didn't intend.

Comment: @Thomas good questions, but I don't know yet how to check that, will try.

Comment: SO question can't require to read a whole project to answer, if you can't put all code nessesary into the question it's not a good SO question, it's a Q&A not a forum, I think you will have way more help on user rust forum or reddit rust. "No need to be this rude." damm NO FUN ALLOWED here as always. your post could clearly be a github issue seriously. Just look, what is the question of this question ? "Rust macro extremely slow (increase expenentially) and with high disk usage" is not a question... and again it's a Q&A site.... I didn't down vote cause this is quality but it's not a question.

Comment: @Stargateur I thought my question was clear and at the very top : "What advice should I follow to keep the compilation time reasonable?". You're right, it may be an issue for github, but where? My project definitively, but that's unhelpful. the crate quote? proc-macro2? the rust project?
Also, I'm learning rust, so I'm asking here for advice how to solve the compilation time. Is it a problem with my way of using those crates? Is it a global problem with macros? Is it an obvious bug in my code? How can I investigate it?

Comment: I think the post you did on user forum is where I would start. Then I think you could create an issue on quote since that "less" official than proc-macro2 anyway that the same creator that wrote the two dtolnay. But I don't know if dtlonay will help you since your problem is complex it would take a lot of time. honestly proc macro and quote are kind of very advanced even for me as a rust veteran. the number of people who can help you is very limited.

Comment: @Stargateur Thank you. I didn't know if my problem was complex or not, thus my question. As my code generate simple boilerplate, I assumed I had missed something obvious and used the proc-macro2 API wrong, or that the way I use it was suboptimal. Also, I cross-posted here because I anticipate to offer a bounty if my problem needed it.

Comment: @Thomas thank you for your pointers, with more digging in that direction, I have been able to pinpoint the culprit: passing from 29k lignes of code to 57k (without macros) multiply by 30 the compilation time by 30 and generate a 13GB file. I will generate less code...

Answer (score 2):

To generate the code created by the macros, the command `cargo +nightly rustc --profile=check -- -Zunpretty=expanded` can be used. (the nightly toolchain must be installed.

Saving that output in a file allows, with very few modifications, to have the same code without using macros.

Regarding https://github.com/tdelmas/floats/compare/macro1...macro2 :

- The code generated (& cleaned) for `macro1`:  https://gist.github.com/tdelmas/484b92a2c86fb8e3d67359127fafb939 (29k lines of codes)
- The code generated (& cleaned) for `macro2`: https://gist.github.com/tdelmas/59c1f972e4f8891202321fdc91a0fd58 (57k lines of codes)

When compiling a project containing the first code, `cargo build` takes ~15 seconds.
With the second code, it takes ~15 minutes.

**The problem doesn't come from the usage of macros, but from the compilation time of the generated code.**

Also, with the second code, you can notice the compiler generated a file `target/debug/incremental/***/query-cache.bin` of **13 GB** which most probably explains the high disk usage at the end of the compilation.

So until the compilation improve, the solution is to generate less code. (the problem still persists with `cargo 1.72.0-nightly (49b6d9e17 2023-06-09)`)

Also, turning off incremental compilation fix the high disk usage and reduce a little the compilation time: https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/profiles.html#incremental

Comment: You can also use cargo expand for expanding the generated code. Does not require nightly once it has been installed